# Control Inheritance with Blend in Silverlight 3

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, blend

i would like to create a custom base class for some of my UserControls. 
Doing this in VS2008 is fine and compiles as expected, but when i edit the control in Blend 3 the base class in the blabla.g.vb is always changed back to System.Windows.Controls.UserControl.

How can i force Blend to keep the assigned base class?

regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your XAML?

I suspect the case is your XAML is like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication15"
             x:Class="SilverlightApplication15.MainPage"
             Width="640"
             Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="#FF313131" />
</UserControl>
```

When it should be something like:

```
<local:BlahBlah xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication15"
                x:Class="SilverlightApplication15.MainPage"
                Width="640"
                Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="#FF313131" />
</local:BlahBlah>
```

The .g.vb file is generated from the XAML so it's not a file you should edit directly.